Adjust font size of \footfullcite
I am trying to cite references by using the command \footfullcite.
However, the font size of footnote with \footfullcite is somewhat too larger than the font size of footnote. (Compare the font size of [1] and [2] with a normal footnote 1 in Figure 1)
What I want to do is to adjust the font size of \footfullcite same as footnote.
I've tried below command but it didn't work.

\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\tiny}

Can you tell me solution please? Thank you.

Welcome to tex.sx.

Maybe you can try \setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\tiny}?

@TeddyvanJerry  Nah, your suggestion didn't work :(
